# How to create Setup file of windows application without using InstallShield in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, installshield, windows

I have developed a windows application (one type of CRM System) but now I want to create its setup file so it can be easily installed on client's machine. I have searched online and found out the way using InstallShield. But it is giving the free trial and then it is offering the paid version. Is there any other way to create Setup file without using InstallShield?

Comment: You could take a look at [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/), but you'll need to write the XML files. If you want a GUI you'll need to spend.

Comment: If you have professional VS 2013 then you can make setup using that. But, if you do not have that then you can switch to VS Community edition.

Comment: You can have a look at the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects or publish a ClickOnce application through Publish Wizard:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.120).aspx, for the detail development issues during your development when you used this technology, you can post it in this forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/home?forum=winformssetup

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension: [VSI_Bundle](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).
See the [The Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)

It worked good for me.

See my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28029063/200824

Answer (score 1):

You can use visual studio 2015 and install installer projects extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at https://wixtoolset.org. A lot of new, helpful elements (grammar is XML) were added to simplify development. So while it's not drag-and-drop design, it's fairly easy to use and 3.x builds MSIs that are still the mainstay on Windows. 4.x pre-releases can also build other formats such as AppX (though, that is only supported on Windows 10 to install).